# Whats the safe minimun value of swappiness?

Tags: linux, systemd, swap

Im looking to make a little faster a system, and I have wonderig if this helps or not, and so whats the min safe level to set it?

Comment: Any level of `vm.swappiness` is safe. Please consult the documentation for such questions: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt Also note that adjusting `vm.swappiness` is not going to “make your system faster” (whatever that is supposed to mean).

Comment: @HenriMenke, Many thanks. The idea is to minimize the swap acces so there is a bit less of lag between the hard disk and the proc.